# Is is possible to dynamically populate a data-icon in Angular Directive?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently trying to dynamically change the value in a data-icon tag? Editing the markup in chrome I can change the icon - just changing the string but if I try to set it as a variable on the scope of my directive and then pass the variable to the data-icon html tag all I see is the passed string, not the relevant icon.

I've tried using sce trust as html, and set up a plunkr utilising [Jquery data icons](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html) but they don't seem to want to change dynamically. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the whole code?

Comment: and set up a plunkr... Where is your plunkr ?